# Problem adding free product to cart in Magento

Tags: magento, product, cart

I have written a buy one get one free module for Magento which works perfectly in Magento 1.3.x.

It extends "`Mage_Checkout_CartController`" to add the free (simple) product to the cart when the qualifying logic is met. I have modified the "`indexAction()`" function in the extended "`CartController.php`" and added the extra code and logic to add the free item which is basically added using

```
$cart->addProduct($FREPRODUCTID, 1);
$cart->save();
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

This works fine in Magento 1.3.x (CE) however in 1.4 and 1.5 what I am seeing is that the free item is added to the cart but the cart total does not update to include the product added by my code, and at checkout the product is not seen. Although the product is free, has a zero price configured, I also notice that when I give the product a price, i.e. $1 the product still shows up with a zero price in the cart as though its simply not recognized. The free product is correctly configured and is saleable, in stock etc.

Any suggestions as to why my product is being added to the cart but somehow is not being correctly seen by the system in Magento 1.4/1.5?

Thanks

PAJ

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code & test it:-

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$product->load($FREPRODUCTID);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$cartItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$counter = 1;
$cartData = array();
if (count($cartItems)) {
    foreach ($cartItems as $_eachItem) {
        $cartData[$counter]['qty'] = $_eachItem->getQty();
        $counter++;
    }
}

$freeProductQty = 1;
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $freeProductQty, 'product' => $FREPRODUCTID));
$cartData[$counter]['qty'] = $freeProductQty;

$cartData = $cart->suggestItemsQty($cartData);
$cart->updateItems($cartData)
     ->save();

$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

In the method "`addProduct()`", I have specifically mentioned the required product object (which is to be added to the Cart) as the first parameter & the array with the quantity of that product as the second parameter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was using
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($FREEPRODUCT);

and $cart = $this->_getCart();

With your suggestion the result is exactly the same. Product is in the cart but does not seem to be recognised, i.e. if there are 5 products in the cart, and the free product is added, the cart total still shows 5. Interestingly if I click on the free product in the cart to view it, and then go back to the cart the product is recognised and the cart total is correct. Remove the product, and add it back in and it is not recognised again...

Comment: OK if I manually update the cart now, the product is seen properly so looks like my cart save/update isn't correct?

Comment: @paj - Can you please check the edited answer & try again, as I have updated the statement where the "`addProduct()`" method is called? I will recommend that you please try this updated solution first.

Comment: @Knowledge Craving unfortunately its still the same. Product is in the cart, but cart total does not update until I manually click update cart.

Comment: @paj - Now, I got it. Since the cart object was being handled by the "`getModel()`" method, so you were not getting the updated results. Instead please try the "`getSingleton()`" method, as in my updated answer. Hope it now works.

Comment: @Knowledge Craving still the same using that method. I was using " $cart = $this->_getCart(); " to get cart contents and determing existing products in cart, so that method was working. Just the cart update doesn't seem to be correct, or has changed from v1.3.x. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You should always use `$product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());` to load product data for current store (price, description, etc. could be different, you know). Without this part you load product from admin store.

Comment: @Zyava - yes, that's been used in here. Sorry, but could not get what you wanted to point to.

Comment: @paj - Can you please try the updated answer for the last time?

Comment: @Craving, the results are exactly the same with all these methods. I think perhaps the problem might lie with the cart renderer and not the product add. My functions to add the free product are called from within indexAction() in cartcontroller.php the code to render the cart is also called there, but this code comes from the original core cartcontroller function.

Comment: @paj - Yes, may be, but I'm also sorry in not being able to provide you the correct answer. May be some other SO user can show you the light. But if you get any answer, please post it here, for people like us, who need to know more about Magento. Best of Luck!

Comment: @craving have a look at the indexAction function in the core cart controller file yourself and simply try adding a product using your code there to see if you see the same results as me in the cart. Thanks for your time and suggestions, I will update this when I resolve the issue.

Comment: @craving, see my second post above.

Answer (score 0):

This should make sure the cart is properly updated :

```
        session_write_close();
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

When I add this to my extended cartcontroller functions after my product add and cart save then the cart renders my added product correctly.